# AngularJS: Filter only users which are not deleted

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying to filter and show only those users which are not deleted (Active) 
where `users` is a table and `deleted_at` is the column(timestamp).

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {user.deleted_at == null}" ng-class="{'success': userData.id == user.id }" style="background-color:{{'userData.color'}}" ng-if="selectedRole == '' || (user.group_list | lookup:GROUPS | lists:'name' | join).indexOf(selectedRole) != -1">
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. I hop it'll help you.

`<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {!user.deleted_at}" ng-class="{'success': userData.id == user.id }" style="background-color:{{'userData.color'}}" ng-if="selectedRole == '' || (user.group_list | lookup:GROUPS | lists:'name' | join).indexOf(selectedRole) != -1">`

Comment: Whats in your users object?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `filter : {deleted_at : null}`

```js
function myctrl($scope){
  $scope.users = [
    {"name":"Hardik Shah", "deleted_at" : null},
    {"name" : "I am deleted", "deleted_at": "2343434"},
    {"name": "I am not deleted", "deleted_at": null}
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app = "" ng-controller="myctrl">
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter : {deleted_at : null}">
  <td>
    {{user.name}}
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Post your users object

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to filter your array and pass it to the `ng-repeat`

```js
function ctrl($scope){
  $scope.users = [
    {id: 1, deleted_at: null},
    {id: 2, deleted_at: "12345"},
    {id: 3, deleted_at: null}
  ]
  $scope.userFilter = user => user.deleted_at
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: userFilter">
    <td>
      {{user.id}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```